# Twirp not working with proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, twirp

I seem to be unable to install twirp correctly to work with protobuf.

```
protoc --proto_path=$GOPATH/bin:. --twirp_out=. --go_out=. ./rpc/person/service.proto
```

is the command I'm trying to do when compiling and creating my twirp file, however I get the following error:

```
protoc-gen-twirp:program not found or is not executable
--twirp_out: protoc-gen-twirp: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

My .bashrc already has these two lines for Golang:

```
export GOPATH=/home/carlosrueda/Documents/go
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/go/bin:$GOPATH
```

Any help to solve this will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You forgot `export` before `PATH=`.

Comment: I tried this and it is still not working.

Comment: Type `which protoc-gen-twirp` in your console.  If it outputs nothing, the binary isn't detected in your PATH.

Comment: Indeed it outputs nothing, how could I fix this?

Comment: I fixed this by adding     /bin at the end of the second line in my .bashrc.

    `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: @CarlosRueda, please post your solution in the answers.

Comment: How did you get the protoc-gen-twirp binary again?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding /bin at the end of the second line in my .bashrc. `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin`